# Oracle Apex Capture session value in collection

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid like this:

```
EMPID   NAME    Active  Dept
1       John    Y       Sales
2       Adam    N       Sales
3       Clark   Y       Sales
4       Sonia   Y       Sales
```

The Active column is a checkbox with Check for Y and not checked for N.
(I am really sorry as I cannot provide a demo)

In database we have table Employee which is the same source for this grid.

In the grid once the employees have been checked as Active/Inactive with Y/N values set using checkbox.
I want a final set of values in the session and list of employees in the table to get the final list of activation status per department

Ex: Lets say in IG, I set John as N and Adam as Y.

In DB table, we have 2 more employees Clark and Sonia both as Y for the Sales department.

So department-wise I want to get the list of employees with final status, i.e.
Updated Employees in current session with latest Active status + Other employees in the db table.

This list would be used to calculate the total salary for only Active employees.

Now once I have list of total employees with active status as Y, there has to be condition before submit. If count(active) >1 only then it should proceed and submit page.

So below the grid I have a submit button which directs to a package that basically updates the total salary in the finance table(second table).

On submit, before going to package I need the validation (count) done, that gets the final status of all Employees set as Active, whether in session+table, so that only those are sent upon submit.

My main query is at what point collection should be created and used here:
The requirement is slightly vague, but I will happily answer any questions if you could help!